# Visual Studio IDE - Jumping cursor out of 'Peek Definition' window

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Is there a command to jump the cursor back back to where it was previous to entering the 'Peek Definition' window without using the mouse?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Window.CloseToolWindow` command to navigate in and out of 'Peek Definition'.


It does not close the embedded window as you'd expect from a command named such as this. But nonetheless it is very useful, and thus the only way I know of navigating in and out of the window.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> should return to your original code place.

Comment: Edit.SelectionCancel